# What is the meaning of the parameter "algorithm" passed to FlannBasedMatcher in OpenCV 3.4.0?

Tags: python, opencv

For the code below, what's the value of the parameter `algorithm = 1` mean?

```
cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(dict(algorithm = 1, trees = 5), {})
```

Not able to find the meaning of it. Does it mean Randomized k-d Tree, Priority Search K-Means Tree or Hierarchical Clustering Tree?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/dc/d8c/namespacecvflann.html) is k-d Tree